# How to debug a content-script loaded in Firefox extention

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've created a firefox addon from an angularjs application I made previously. I'm injecting this app into the extention as a content script so I can make XHR requests to an API. However I do not seem to be able to debug the content scripts when I run the app using JPM. The docs mention mention a caveat about debugging content scripts [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger#Content_scripts) it doesn't explain how to actually debug them.

I feel I'm just missing something obvious. I was able to debug the add-on the first time I loaded it. But not since. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you enable the dev preferences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences if you do that then you should see all errors in the browser console

Answer (score 1):

The Content script you can debug in firebug itself. once you load the page check the firebug script list it will listed on that.

Comment: The latest Firebug doesn't support debugging addons. It's been apparently an issue since 2012

Comment: I am using Firefox version 38 with Firebug Version 2.0.12. I can debug my content script. see the [Link](http://s14.postimg.org/xmy8mgkwx/Screenshot_from_2015_09_18_03_19_19.png). PageLoad.js was my content script